# Mysterious claim in Casella's book

Tags: probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I'm studying by [Statistical Inference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0534243126) by Casella and Berger and on page 225, I didn't understand why he expected the $F$ distribution behaved in this way (see the highlighted part in the end of the image).

[image]

Let's $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_m$ random samples of $N(\mu_X,\sigma^2_X)$ and $N(\mu_Y,\sigma^2_Y)$ respectively. So why it's expected the $F$ distribution goes to $1$ for a large $m$ and why this is important? (I'm sorry it's the first time I'm studying $F$ distributions, I'm not aware why it's so important and what the important features are)

Comment: I guess it's important because it tells you that the estimated ratio of variances converges to the actual ratio of variances.

Comment: The last but second line is a *brave* argument of the form: $E(X_n)\to c$ implies, by *removing expectations*, that $X_n \sim c$.

Comment: @Chaos it doesn't matter the distributions as long as they are normal?